# How to generate the HTML file using Plotly Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, plotly

After using the sample code want to generate the HTML for the plot `plot.makeFile()` throws the below exception even passed a custom path still there are errors in generating the HTML file using

implementation("kscience.plotlykt:plotlykt-core:0.2.0")

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Path.of(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;
    at kscience.plotly.PlotlyHeadersKt$systemPlotlyHeader$1.invoke(plotlyHeaders.kt:39)
    at kscience.plotly.PlotlyHeadersKt$systemPlotlyHeader$1.invoke(plotlyHeaders.kt)
    at kscience.plotly.HtmlKt.toHTML(html.kt:34)
    at kscience.plotly.FileExportKt.makeFile(fileExport.kt:53)
    at kscience.plotly.FileExportKt.makeFile$default(fileExport.kt:49)
    at UndefinedKt.main(Undefined.kt:30)
    at UndefinedKt.main(Undefined.kt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used here is introduced in Java 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)

You need to use JDK 11 or newer to run it. If I remember properly, newer versions won't even work with something below JDK 11. So just use newer JDK. If for some reason you are not able to do so, please open an issue here: https://github.com/mipt-npm/plotly.kt/issues. We can roll back to 1.8 bytecode.